# Mostrar contenido de una variable en html desde php

Tags: php, html

soy nuevo en php y estoy intentando mostrar en un textbox el contenido de una variable de php pero no lo logro, todo el codigo esta en el mismo archivo.

```
<html>
```

Numero Plazas, Hora

```
<div id="contenedor">

    <div id="logo" >
        <img  src="img/logo coche-reloj.png"/>
    </div>

    <form method="post"  >

        <label>Nombre:</label> <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" value=""
        <br/>
        <label>Hora:</label>  <input id="hora" type="text" name="hora" value=""> 
        <br/>             
        <label>Nº de Plazas:</label> <input id="plaza" type="text" name="plaza">

    </form>

</div>
```

y el codigo php esta justo encima de esto y no se como mostrar la variable .

```
   <?php
/*header( "refresh:20;url=aa.php" );*/
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'parkingchulo');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$ID = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Nombre1']);
$Password =mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['passw1']);
function SignIn()
{
session_start();   //Inicia sesion
if(!empty($_POST['Nombre1']))   //Mira si el nombre que obtienes del login tiene contenido o esta vacio
{


        $ID = $row['IDUsuario'];
        $hora = date('H:i:s');
        $array = range (11,30);
        $Estado = "OCUPADO";
        $directivo2 = '2';
        $queryduplicado = mysql_query("Select IDUsuario from plazas where IDUsuario = $ID");
        $numerorows = mysql_num_rows($queryduplicado);
        $y = '1' ;
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO horas (ID,Nombre,FECHA,HORA,Accion) VALUES ('$ID','$nombre','$hoy','$hora','Entrada Parking')");

    /* Asignacion de plaza falta meter que lo guarde en la bbdd con una query */




    if  ($row['Cargo'] == "directivo1" && $y > $numerorows) {
    $sql = "UPDATE `plazas` SET `OCUPACION`='OCUPADO', `IDUsuario`='$ID' WHERE  `NUMPLAZA`='1'";
    echo $numerorows ;
    $resultado = mysql_query($sql); 
    echo "Has entrado en el parking a las " . date("h:i:sa")." " . $row['Nombre'];
    echo "Tu plaza es la num 1";
    header( "refresh:5;url=aa.php" );
         }
    elseif ($row['Cargo'] == "directivo2" && $y > $numerorows) {
    /* Esta es la query miguel que cambia a ocupado la plaza num 2 */$sql = "UPDATE `plazas` SET `OCUPACION`='OCUPADO' , `IDUsuario`='$ID'  WHERE  `NUMPLAZA`='2'";
    $resultado = mysql_query($sql); 
    echo "Has entrado en el parking a las " . date("h:i:sa")." " . $row['Nombre'];
    echo "Tu plaza es la num 2";

    header( "refresh:5;url=aa.php" ); /*Esta funcion es la que se encarga de almacenar el valor "ocupado"*/
}            /* Lo de los minusvalidos esta bien */
        elseif ($row['Cargo'] == "minusvalido" && $y > $numerorows){
            $plazaminusvalido= mysql_query("SELECT NUMPLAZA FROM plazas WHERE OCUPACION LIKE 'Libre' AND NUMPLAZA BETWEEN 3 AND 7 ORDER BY NUMPLAZA, NUMPLAZA LIMIT 1 ");


            $plazam = mysql_result($plazaminusvalido,0);
            $sql = "UPDATE `plazas` SET `OCUPACION`='OCUPADO',`IDUsuario`='$ID' WHERE  `NUMPLAZA`='$plazam'";
             $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
             header( "refresh:5;url=aa.php" );
             echo "Has entrado en el parking a las " . date("h:i:sa")." " . $row['Nombre'];
             echo "Tu numero de plaza es:$plazam ";
            }
            /*Esto esta bien */
            elseif ($row['Cargo'] == "empleado" && $y > $numerorows){
        $plazaempleado= mysql_query("SELECT NUMPLAZA FROM plazas WHERE OCUPACION LIKE 'Libre' AND NUMPLAZA BETWEEN 8 AND 20 ORDER BY NUMPLAZA, NUMPLAZA LIMIT 1 ");
                echo "Has entrado en el parking a las " . date("h:i:sa")." " . $row['Nombre'];

                $plazaemple = mysql_result($plazaempleado,0);
                $sql = "UPDATE `plazas` SET `OCUPACION`='OCUPADO', `IDUsuario`='$ID' WHERE  `NUMPLAZA`='$plazaemple'";
                 $resultado = mysql_query($sql);
                 echo "Tu plaza es la numero $plazaemple";
                 header( "refresh:5;url=aa.php" );
            }
                else echo "Tienes una plaza ya, antes de entrar de nuevo sal ≧◉ᴥ◉≦" ;
                echo '<input required  type = "text" name = "subject1" value=" Ya tienes plaza" />';
                }

    /* 6-7 RESPONSABLES 8-10 EMPLEADOS */
    else
    {echo "no funciona";}
    $mes = date ('m');
    $año = date ('Y');
    $hoyy = date ('d');


        /* te saca un mensaje en funcion de la hora actual*/
if ($t < "12") {
    echo  nl2br ("\n Buenos dias");
} elseif ($t <20){ 
echo nl2br ("\n Buenas tardes");
} else {
    echo  nl2br ("\n Buenas noches");
}
    }
    else

    {
        echo "No saca mensaje ni redirecciona";


    }
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}

?>
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código de php e indícanos la variable que quieres mostrar en el html.

Comment: Vale y la pregunta aun queda en el aire, los ejemplos que veo dicen que solo entre comillas y con $ <?php echo("la variable la llamo asi '$variableDesdeHTML')
?> si eso es correcto, pues no me funciona gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para imprimir y mostrar variables de php en tu codigo html puedes utilizar `echo`

```
<div id="contenedor">

<div id="logo" >
    <img  src="img/logo coche-reloj.png"/>
</div>

<form method="post"  >

    <label>Nombre:</label> <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre;?>"
    <br/>
    <label>Hora:</label>  <input id="hora" type="text" name="hora" value="<?php echo $hora;?>"> 
    <br/>             
    <label>Nº de Plazas:</label> <input id="plaza" type="text" name="plaza" value="<?php echo $numero_plazas;?>">

</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

En PHP **echo** muestra una o más cadenas el contenido que tiene esa variable.

**echo** no es una función (es una construcción del lenguaje), por lo que no se requiere el uso de paréntesis con él.

EJEMPLO:

```
<?php
echo "Hola mundo";

// Se pueden usar variables dentro de una sentencia echo
$foo = "foobar";
$bar = "barbaz";

echo "foo es $foo"; // foo es foobar

?>
```

Y dado a tu ejemplo seria en el html de la siguiente manera:

```
<div id="contenedor">

<form method="post">

    <label>Nombre:</label> 
    <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre;?>"
    <br/>
    <label>Hora:</label>  
    <input id="hora" type="text" name="hora" value="<?php echo $hora;?>"> 
    <br/>             
    <label>Plazas:</label> 
    <input id="plaza" type="text" name="plaza" value="<?php echo $plaza;?>">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

si lo que quieres es mostrar el valor de una variable en un input, te recomiendo lo siguiente.

1. cambiar la extrension del archivo html a .php Ejemplo (index.html => index.php)
2. en el campo input deberas poner en el value con las etiquetas de apertura de php y cierre, y hacer un echo de la variable a mostrar.

Lastimosamente no me deja mostrar el ejemplo, pero espero a ver sido de ayuda.

con esto podras poner el valor en los inputs.

espero te sirva.